# How to use Case and Count in Single query

Tags: sql, hive, count, case, aggregate-functions

can someone please guide me how to rewrite this query.

i need to take the state count if country='I' else need to assign as 0  based on id Column.

```
    SELECT id,case when country = 'I' then count(state) else 0 end as state_cnt
    FROM info_cntry group by id;
```

but its throwing error like count is not yet supported.

Answer (score 0):

It this what you want?

```
select id,
    count(case when country = 'I' then state end) as state_cnt
from info_cntry 
group by id;
```

On the other hand, if there is just one `country` per `id`, then just add it to the `group by` clause of your original query:

```
select id, 
    case when country = 'I' then count(state) else 0 end as state_cnt
from info_cntry
group by id, country
```